# SQL How to Get Total Number of Films Out On Rent?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm practicing SQL with given results using MySQL Sakila database.

Here's one of the problems I'm struggling with now.

How many films are out on rent?
  Correct Result:   183

I'm inner joining **inventory**,**film**, and **rental tables** for this.

In inventory table, I have `inventory_id`, `film_id`, `store_id`, and `last_update`

In film table, I have`film_id`, `title`, `description`, `release_year`, `language_id`, `original_language_id`, `rental_duration`, `rental_rate`, `length`, `replacement_cost`, `rating`, `special_features`, `last_update`

And for rental table, I have `rental_id`, `rental_date`, `inventory_id`, `customer_id`, `return_date`, `staff_id`, `last_update`

And here's my SQL statement

```
SELECT 
inv.film_id, COUNT(f.title) as numOfDVDsOnRent
FROM
rental AS r
    INNER JOIN
inventory AS inv ON r.inventory_id = inv.inventory_id
inner join film as f on inv.film_id=f.film_id
```

What I've got for the result so far was rows of total number of DVDs out on rent for each film...Something like this:

[image]

So, how can I get the correct result?

Comment: There has to be a column in your inventory file that tells you whether the film is out or not, right? So you probably will need to do something with that column in the WHERE, won't you?

Comment: Remove the group by. I advise you learn SQL first before attempting to play around with it (group by is a very beginner thing imo).

Comment: Do you mean like films that haven't been returned yet? I mean for the word, 'out on rent'?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please show us more about the table structure you are using.  Please include sample data for each table.

Comment: Where a `rental` has not been returned yet is the value of `return_date` stored as `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT COUNT( inventory_id ) as numOfDVDsOnRent
FROM rental
WHERE return_date IS NULL;
```

All the information to determine how many films are out on rent is included in `rental`.  We do not need to refer to the details about each `film` or about each item of `inventory` to determine this, so I have dumped the `INNER JOIN`s.  Note : Where `JOIN` is not preceeded by a join type, an `INNER JOIN` is performed, so you can just type `JOIN` if you wish.

Thus all we need to do is count all the entries in `rental` where the entry has not been returned date.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: No worries - it's something that I do too often, also.  :)